# android butterknife not showing Generate butterknife generate injections in Android Studio4.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx, butterknife

I am trying to use butter knife in updated android studio 4.1.2 but not getting **generate butterknife injection** in **Generate** option.

I have already added **Plugin**: Android ButterKnife Zelezny

build gradle(Project)
/

```
/ Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.2.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.a.b"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    //butterknnife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'

}
```

after adding all this and restart android studio not getting butterknife injection option in generate

Comment: Note that [Butterknife was declared deprecated by its author about a year ago](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)

Comment: @CommonsWare so is there any way to use it in android studio 4.1.2

Comment: I recommend that you use something else, just as the Butterknife author (Jake Wharton) recommends that you use something else. [View binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) is the current leading alternative.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for help found solution and look for view binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying and searching I found **Butterknife** is deprecated so it will not show

**generate butterknife injection**

from **Generate** option when click `R.layout.abc.xml.`

**Solution 1**

but it still works only you have to declare it **manually** like as below

```
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.iv_upload)
    ImageView ivUpload;
    @BindView(R.id.textView)
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abc);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

as @CommonsWare recommendation in comment that use something else,

[View binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) is the current leading alternative.

Answer (score 0):

All dependency declarations look fine. Please do a clean build that should solve the issue.

FYI You do not need to apply the butterknife plugin and the

```
classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.2.3'
```

You just need to have the following dependencies in app build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
```

Comment: thanks for quick response but already tried this but no luck

Comment: as mention in question it doesn't show  generate butterknife injection in Generate when i click R.layout.abc.xml.

Comment: You should see something like this  @BindView